# Android ViewPager tutorial makes no sense

Tags: android, android-fragments

I went on the Android developer site to read how to swipe between pages. So I followed their tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#viewpager

I created a Fragment which inflates the desired views which I want on each swipe page. I then created a FragmentActivity as well as an adapter which creates a new Fragment each swipe. But then the tutorial ended there. Right now I just have a blank screen and I don't even know if the PageViewer is even working. Nowhere in their tutorial did they mention how to assign things to each page swipe. Example: First page swipe I want a textview and a image, next swipe will contain a different textview and a different image, etc. (only 3). This'll be the opening screen of my app before the user gets directed to my main activity.

I know that when I use recyclerview, we are able to assign things to each row. Is there nothing of that sort in the ViewPager?

I pretty much have everything the same as the android site:

Fragment Activity:

```
public class ScreenSlideActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private static final int NUM_PAGES = 3;

ViewPager mPager;
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    int pos = mPager.getCurrentItem();

    if (pos == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else mPager.setCurrentItem(pos - 1);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_slide);

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);



}


private class adapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
}
}
```

Fragment

```
public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, container, false);
    return group;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I know that when I use recyclerview, we are able to assign things to each row. Is there nothing of that sort in the ViewPager?

You would do that inside of your fragment, as you do with any other fragment. Typically, you tell the fragment the general parameters of what it is supposed to be showing when you create it (or update that information via a setter method), and the fragment updates its widgets as appropriate.

For example, in [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Files/FilesEditor), I have my `SampleAdapter` (a `FragmentPagerAdapter` subclass) pass in a file to be loaded into the `newInstance()` factory method of my `EditorFragment`:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2012-2015 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    https://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.fileseditor;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import java.io.File;

public class SampleAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
  private static final int[] TITLES={R.string.internal,
      R.string.external, R.string.pub};
  private static final int TAB_INTERNAL=0;
  private static final int TAB_EXTERNAL=1;
  private static final String FILENAME="test.txt";
  private final Context ctxt;

  public SampleAdapter(Context ctxt, FragmentManager mgr) {
    super(mgr);

    this.ctxt=ctxt;
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return(3);
  }

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    File fileToEdit;

    switch(position) {
      case TAB_INTERNAL:
        fileToEdit=new File(ctxt.getFilesDir(), FILENAME);
        break;

      case TAB_EXTERNAL:
        fileToEdit=new File(ctxt.getExternalFilesDir(null), FILENAME);
        break;

      default:
        fileToEdit=
            new File(Environment.
                  getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS),
                FILENAME);
        break;
    }

    return(EditorFragment.newInstance(fileToEdit));
  }

  @Override
  public String getPageTitle(int position) {
    return(ctxt.getString(TITLES[position]));
  }
}
```

`EditorFragment` stashes that information in the arguments `Bundle` (so the `File` survives a configuration change, like a screen rotation), then uses an `AsyncTask` to load the text content and pour it into the `EditText` that makes up the bulk of the `EditorFragment` UI. It also kicks off a `SaveThread` to update the file when the fragment is paused:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2012-2015 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    https://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.fileseditor;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

public class EditorFragment extends Fragment {
  private static final String KEY_FILE="file";
  private EditText editor;
  private LoadTextTask loadTask=null;
  private boolean loaded=false;

  static EditorFragment newInstance(File fileToEdit) {
    EditorFragment frag=new EditorFragment();
    Bundle args=new Bundle();

    args.putSerializable(KEY_FILE, fileToEdit);
    frag.setArguments(args);

    return(frag);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setRetainInstance(true);
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                           ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View result=inflater.inflate(R.layout.editor, container, false);

    editor=(EditText)result.findViewById(R.id.editor);

    return(result);
  }

  @Override
  public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    if (!loaded) {
      loadTask=new LoadTextTask();
      loadTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,
          (File)getArguments().getSerializable(KEY_FILE));
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    if (loaded) {
      new SaveThread(editor.getText().toString(),
          (File)getArguments().getSerializable(KEY_FILE)).start();
    }

    super.onPause();
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    if (loadTask!=null) {
      loadTask.cancel(false);
    }

    super.onDestroy();
  }

  private class LoadTextTask extends AsyncTask<File, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(File... files) {
      String result=null;

      if (files[0].exists()) {
        BufferedReader br;

        try {
          br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(files[0]));

          try {
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
            String line=br.readLine();

            while (line!=null) {
              sb.append(line);
              sb.append("\n");
              line=br.readLine();
            }

            result=sb.toString();
          }
          finally {
            br.close();
          }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
          Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Exception reading file", e);
        }
      }

      return(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
      editor.setText(s);
      loadTask=null;
      loaded=true;
    }
  }

  private static class SaveThread extends Thread {
    private final String text;
    private final File fileToEdit;

    SaveThread(String text, File fileToEdit) {
      this.text=text;
      this.fileToEdit=fileToEdit;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      try {
        fileToEdit.getParentFile().mkdirs();

        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(fileToEdit);

        Writer w=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));

        try {
          w.write(text);
          w.flush();
          fos.getFD().sync();
        }
        finally {
          w.close();
        }
      }
      catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Exception writing file", e);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The same pattern holds true for many other scenarios (e.g., the `PagerAdapter` gives a database primary key to the fragment, which queries the database and populates its widgets).

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. Your code is too advanced for me. In layman terms, what should I add to my Fragment class?

Comment: @SheilaGrant: "In layman terms, what should I add to my Fragment class?" -- code to fill in the widgets from your `fragment_screen_slide_page` layout file with whatever you want those widgets to show. Again, this is no different than with any other fragment. If you have never used fragments before, you might wish to consider putting this work aside for a while and gaining some experience with using fragments in general, before you start trying to use a `ViewPager` and `FragmentPagerAdapter`.